# Is it possible to use BitmapFactory.decodeFile method to decode a image from http location?

Tags: android, http, bitmap

I would like to know if it is possible to use BitmapFactory.decodeFile method to decode a image from http location?

For eg.

```
ImageView imageview = new ImageView(context);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("http://<my IP>/test/abc.jpg");  
imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

But bmp is always returning null.

Is there any other way to achieve this scenario, where i have a set of images in my server PC, and i am loading the images to my gallery application via an xml?

Thanks,
Sen

Comment: i hope , you are getting Skia Decoder Returned false, Be sure that you are yielding this message or not, check Your Logcat, for this message????

Comment: @Sankar : ya, i checked the logcat, i am __NOT__ "getting the Skia Decoder Returned false" message.

Comment: Then tell me what messages, you had got in your Logcat?

Comment: @Sankar : I am trying to pass the images to the Gallery, So the above steps are being implemented in the getView method of my Avtivity. All i get is that bmp is null in all positions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Amir & @Sankar :  Thanks for your valuable suggestions.

I solved the above problem by doing the following code snippet :

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);

try{
    String url1 = "http://<my IP>/test/abc.jpg";
    URL ulrn = new URL(url1);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)ulrn.openConnection();
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    if (null != bmp)
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    else
        System.out.println("The Bitmap is NULL");

} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

Thanks,
Sen

Comment: Do not forget to disconnect (and hereby release the input stream resource), e.g.
`finally {
    if (con != null) {
        con.disconnect();
    }
}`
Ref: [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Answer (score 16):

Use decodeStream and pass the URL's inputstream instead.

Here is an example:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new java.net.URL(url).openStream())
```

Comment: Did you mean :   Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream("http://<my IP>/test/abc.jpg");  ?

Comment: How to pass the URL's inputstream??

Answer (score 5):

```
String urldisplay="http://www.google.com/";//sample url
Log.d("url_dispaly",urldisplay);
try{    
InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
Bitmap  mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new SanInputStream(in));
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

Create class name SanInputStream

```
public class SanInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
      public SanInputStream(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
      }
      public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        long m = 0L;
        while (m < n) {
          long _m = in.skip(n-m);
          if (_m == 0L) break;
          m += _m;
        }

        return m;
      }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of SanInputStream?

Comment: @Amir Raminfar: The BitmapFactory.decodeStream() method fails to read a JPEG image (i.e. returns null) if the skip() method of the used FilterInputStream  skip less bytes than the required amount. That's i had used that skip method of FilterInputStream in My class SanInputStream

Comment: Hmm never had that problem. I am reading PNGs, JPEGs and everything else just fine. Is this a bug in 1.6+ maybe?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, @Sen code snippet should return null in case of .BMP file and logcat should log:

```
skia decoder->decode returned false
```

If something like this is happening, try using this code (works also in case of bitmap input):

```
HttpGet httpRequest = null;

try {
    httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);

InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();

bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);
```

[Source](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/10a3821158f17be1)

Answer (score 0):

// Create an object for subclass of AsyncTask

```
GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
```

// Execute the task

```
task.execute(new String[] { "ImageURL" });
```

//then in Asyntask class assign the image to image view to avoid android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

```
private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap map = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            map = downloadImage(url);
        }
        return map;
    }

    // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                    decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
}
```