# download an image and save it in android

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-download-manager

I would like to download just one image from an URL then save it (to my folder) . this image is user's avatar. I've found the following links:

[Best method to download image from url in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210700/best-method-to-download-image-from-url-in-android)

[Android Download Image From URL and show in Imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161137/android-download-image-from-url-and-show-in-imageview)

how can I do ?

what is the best solution? (Except Download manager)

Answer (score 3):

The best way is use [picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Its dead simple just put this one line where you want to load the image. Picasso supports image caching also so you doint have to worry about downloading and caching the image.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many frameworks are available for this. Like

- DownloadManager
- Picasso
- AndroidQuery

But I am using AndroidQuery since 3 years and have great experience with this framework.

It cache the images it self and manage duplication of image download. And Really faster and light weight.

You can download the jar from [Here](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/detail?name=android-query-full.0.26.7.jar&can=2&q=)