# How to load Image and other content in UI from server

Tags: android, android-networking

Taking example of viewpager or recyclerview in android we know that they can contain images as well.What i want to know is that how we can load images from database from server and put that images in view pager or recycler view.Upto know my understanding is that i have to make a database in server and put images in it ,now during splash screen download that images and after that put that images into view.Am i going right? Basically what i want to achieve is like shopping app which shows images which changes time to time ? how i can do same ?Do i should go with Rest API to download that images from server and then put in view also do i need to make sure that every time user opens app then it download image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Download Image From URL and show in Imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161137/android-download-image-from-url-and-show-in-imageview)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply fetch .jpg URL from API and then load that image in your app by using Fresco library.

Check this out: [Display images with Fresco](https://guides.codepath.com/android/displaying-images-with-the-fresco-library)

First add Fresco to your dependencies in app/build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.10.0'
}
```

Don't forget to add in your AndroidManifest.xml proper permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Initialize Fresco in class that extend `Application` class. You can do it in `Activity`, but it's better to do it just once in `Application` class.

```
Fresco.initialize(context);
```

Instead of `ImageView` use `SimpleDraweeView` like this:

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/sdvImage"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/myPlaceholderImage" />
```

Then just init your `SimpleDraweeView` object in Activity/ViewHolder/Fragment, parse Url string to Uri like this:

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("https://i.imgur.com/tGbaZCY.jpg");
```

And you can set Uri to your `SimpelDraweeView` object this way:

```
draweeView.setImageURI(imageUri);
```

You can use Glide or Picasso as well. Find one that suit your needs by read this post:

[Picasso v/s Imageloader v/s Fresco vs Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide)