# How to transform a JPG URL remote Image into a Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, jpeg

i want to get a remote JPG file from a URL (  http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/spanish/ravsberg_442x330jpg.jpg ) and have it into a Bitmap.

I'm trying to use this code:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return null;
}
```

But the code is failing on the line: `InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();`

I'm getting this exception:

```
    03-15 16:08:40.171: WARN/System.err(6526): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/spanish/ravsberg_442x330jpg.jpg
03-15 16:08:40.186: WARN/System.err(6526):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
03-15 16:08:40.186: WARN/System.err(6526):     at com.Magazine.Util.getBitmapFromURL(Util.java:69)
03-15 16:08:40.194: WARN/System.err(6526):     at com.Magazine.magazine.getMiniature(magazine.java:32)
03-15 16:08:40.194: WARN/System.err(6526):     at com.Magazine.MainMenu.generatePortraitGrid(MainMenu.java:141)
03-15 16:08:40.202: WARN/System.err(6526):     at com.Magazine.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:113)
03-15 16:08:40.210: WARN/System.err(6526):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-15 16:08:40.210: WARN/System.err(6526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-15 16:08:40.210: WARN/System.err(6526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-15 16:08:40.210: WARN/System.err(6526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-15 16:08:40.217: WARN/System.err(6526):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-15 16:08:40.217: WARN/System.err(6526):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-15 16:08:40.217: WARN/System.err(6526):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-15 16:08:40.225: WARN/System.err(6526):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-15 16:08:40.225: WARN/System.err(6526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 16:08:40.225: WARN/System.err(6526):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-15 16:08:40.225: WARN/System.err(6526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
03-15 16:08:40.225: WARN/System.err(6526):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-15 16:08:40.233: WARN/System.err(6526):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: does it work when run with a Oracle JVM?

Comment: what¿?¿? i'm programming with Android

Comment: do you have internet connection? have you added the USES_INTERNET permission?

Comment: yes, i have internet permission and internet connection. In fact, another previous part of the app is connecting to internet to get the URL of the jpg and it's working because i'm getting the correct URL of the JPG

Comment: of course you are programming android, but apart from the Bitmap class this is core Java code. You can run it in a regular VM. It runs successfully on mine.

Comment: Does it work for other URLs at this point in the program? Maybe the BBC doesn't like non-browser, mobile requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see your Internet Permission in Manifest, and check the url is right too.
  I use the function "urlImageToBitmap(String urlImage)" i got of this page:
http://www.tutorialandroid.com/basico/como-pasar-de-drawable-a-bitmap-y-descargar-imagen-de-internet-a-bitmap/
  I hope it help you!

Comment: I have internet permission in manifest. The URL of the JPG is right.

Comment: weird... i've checked again the function i told you and it works.
Try create a new proyect with only this function. It help to trace the problem

Answer (score 1):

Look at this work-aroud: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4510418/1216540
It worked for me.

Best regards