# Android - download attached image from URL

Tags: android, image, download

There is a URL, without an image extension, that wherever go to it in the browser it will download an image.

In fiddler, I can see the response like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 21 Dec 2014 08:08:53 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpg
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="current.jpg"
```

I want to be able to get that "current.jpg" image and add it to an imageview.
I've tried with

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

But this will make my imageview blank.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509912/is-it-possible-to-use-bitmapfactory-decodefile-method-to-decode-a-image-from-htt

Comment: @JASONGPETERSON that question won't help me. The bitmap will always be null, because the bitmap is an attachment, my url does not end with .jpg or .png..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AQuery library](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/) to load images from network.

Comment: Why would I use that? Did you tried to use it and it worked with attached images?